# Drop-down Menu Moves Overflow of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table. This table lists the details of the patients. I wanted to add a drop down menu to do some function. But the drop-down menu overflow from the right and bottom. I dont want this. I want the drop-down menu to always remain inside the screen.

So if the menu is overflow from the right, opening to the left. If the menu is overflow from the bottom, opening to the top.

Here is the codes,

https://jsfiddle.net/um1vr3wq/

I did a lot of research. I found some codes. But it didn't work properly for me.

This code adds the "reverse-right" class to all div that have the same class. I dont want this. I just want it added to the clicked div.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth < 1730) {
        $('.dropdown-content').addClass('reverse-right');
    }
    else {
        $('.dropdown-content').removeClass('reverse-right');
    }
});
```

This code works correctly. But it's not what I want. This sets the position only when ".dropbtn" is clicked. I want the menu position to change when I reduce or enlarge the page instantly.

```
$(".dropbtn").click(function () {
    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 1730) {
        $(this).parents(".dropdown").children(".dropdown-content").addClass("reverse-right");
    }
    else {
      $(this).parents(".dropdown").children(".dropdown-content").removeClass("reverse-right");
    }
});
```

I'm new to Javascript and need a definite solution. Can you help me?

(Sorry for my bad english. Im working on it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some calculations of dropdown box top and left position including it's height & width. And toggle classes to reverse it's position.

**Here is link**

```
> https://codepen.io/AsfanShaikh/pen/PooeazY
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way I want. "I want the menu position to change when I reduce or enlarge the page instantly."

Comment: I have updated `CodePen`. Now its' working on `window` `resize` and `scroll` also.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. But one more problem. How to fix this? My English is not enough to explain it :D    youtu.be/sV2SNgNHEdM     and this  
   youtu.be/OCiv58OZIGY

Comment: Shaik https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sV2SNgNHEdM&feature=youtu.be and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCiv58OZIGY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Sorry for delay... Updated CodePen demo. There was some miscalculation in demo. Check now. I hope it's working fine now.  Fixed now. :)

Comment: It works perfectly. Everything's good now. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hey, can you help me again? I couldn't figure this out. I think the problem is CSS. https://prnt.sc/q6mfb6 https://codepen.io/lastofdead/pen/WNbvXRP